# Python/Selenium: HTMLUNIT Driver Connection Refused - Port Blocked

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I am trying to set up and use HTMLUnit driver in Python 3. I believe I have the server running (v3.7.0) and believe the code should work based looking up other questions on here. I believe that the remote server uses port 4444 but my ISP locks that port down (along with basically every other port). Currently when I run the code I get a connection refused. Is this to do with the port being closed? Can I change the port to 8080 (which is open)?

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNITWITHJS)
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

Current output:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection refused>
```

Comment: Are you able to launch any other browser? Also is the server running on the same machine or a external machine? Because if server runs on same machine then port blocking may not matter

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes, I can launch with Chrome and Safari with no issue but I would like to try HTMLUnit as it appears to be the fastest browser. Yes, the server is running on the same machine. I ran it by typing `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.7.0.jar` into the terminal window in Pycharm.

Comment: when you say chrome works? Did you run it using `driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)`

Comment: @TarunLalwani no I did not try and run chrome remotely.

Comment: If you are doing it on a local machine then only thing that would block access is a firewall. ISP won't come into picture when you are testing on a local system

Answer (score 0):

From this [Link](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#htmlunit-driver):

You can use:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNITWITHJS)
```